# Python card game - trying to append a popped object from one class to another

Tags: python, class, append, card

the following python code is what I am working on :

```
import random

ranks = ["Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
suits = ["Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds"]

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        
    def print(self):
        print(self.rank, "of", self.suit)

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        
    def build(self):
        for x in ranks:
            for y in suits:
                self.cards.append(Card(x,y))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def print(self):
        for x in self.cards:
            x.print()

    def draw(self):
        self.cards.pop()
        
y = Deck()
y.build()
y.shuffle()

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def take(self):
        self.hand.append()
        
    def print(self):
        for x in self.hand:
            x.print()

z = Player()
z.take()
z.print()
```

For the life of me I cant seem to get z.take() and z.print() to work. I can get Class Deck to pop a card and then show it using that Class method, but I cant seem to get the card into the Class Player's hand. How would I append the card to Class Player's hand? If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You probably shouldn't name your function *print*

Comment: In the function `take()` you are appending nothing to the hand.

Comment: @BrutusForcus it's not as bad if it is an instance method, this way it can't be called without a reference to the instance

Comment: `card = y.pop() ` `z.take(card)`. But it needs `return self.cards.pop()` and `def take(self, card): self.hand.append(card)`

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `return` in

```
    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()
```

Next you should use argument (ie. `card`) in

```
    def take(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)
```

And then you can do

```
card = y.draw()
z.take(card)
```

or

```
z.take(y.draw())
```

---

**BTW:**

And you could use better names instead of `x`, `y`, `z` - to make code more readable.

---

```
import random

# --- constants ---  # `UPPER_CASE_NAMES`

RANKS = ["Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"]
SUITS = ["Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds"]

# --- classes ---

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        
    def print(self):
        print(self.rank, "of", self.suit)

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        
    def build(self):
        for rank in RANKS:
            for suit in SUITS:
                self.cards.append(Card(rank, suit))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def print(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.print()

    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []

    def take(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)
        
    def print(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.print()

# --- functions ---

# empty

# --- main ---

deck = Deck()
deck.build()
deck.shuffle()

player1 = Player()
player2 = Player()

for _ in range(5):
    card = deck.draw()
    player1.take(card)

    card = deck.draw()
    player2.take(card)

print('--- player 1 ---')
player1.print()

print('--- player 2 ---')
player2.print()
```

And version with lists and for-loops

Because names (single) `player` and (many) `players` are very similar and sometimes it can make mistakes in code so I use prefix `all_` to make `all_players` and `player` simpler to recognize.

```
# --- main ---

deck = Deck()
deck.build()
deck.shuffle()

all_players = [Player(), Player(), Player(), Player()]

for player in all_players:
    for _ in range(5):
        card = deck.draw()
        player.take(card)

for number, player in enumerate(all_players, 1):
    print('--- player', number, '---')
    player.print()
```